# Opencv compile with ffmpeg for android

Tags: linux, opencv, ffmpeg, android

I am using opencv-2.4-10 in my use case.

I want to compile opencv with ffmpeg support for android platform. I have enable ffmpeg option from cmake but still i can't enable opencv with ffmpeg support.

Actually my application going to open avi file but it's give me error like "Cannot open the video file"

Here is the my code:

```
VideoCapture cap("test.avi");


if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
{
cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
return -1;
}
```